# MS Access Error: Invalid field definition 'CON474' in definition of index or relationship

Tags: microsoft-access, odbc, db2

Looking for some help with a MS Access problem.

I am creating a bunch of linked tables between Access and our AS400 (iSeries) system. I have some OBDC DSN's set up and can access the system without issue.
A few however give me the below error (typically the more important ones):
Invalid field definition 'CON474' in definition of index or relationship
CON474 would imply it's the file name but when I check the file in Query400 it doesn't seem to be a field name or code within that file - odd!

Anyone have any previous similar issues or any suggestions to resolve.
My backup solution is creating in Excel PowerQuery which works with these files but is generally painful and clunky.

Thanks
Ben